# Spring Boot JPA : identifier of an instance of bingo.model.Group was altered from 1702 to null

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**I have a Short Question:**
Last Save is working(Last Save will be Update).
But First Save is not working.(First Save will be Insert)
I can't insert this way, how is it possible?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/delete/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable BigInteger id, Model model) {
        try {
                Group group = groupService.findById(id);
                group.setId(null);
                group.isLog(true);
                // This Save will be Insert Data
                groupService.save(group);

                group = groupService.findById(id);
                group.isLog(true);
                //This Save will be Update Data
                groupService.save(group);

            return "redirect:/accountsGroup/";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "masters/accountsInfo/groups/index";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also show the Group Entity code?

Comment: Why are you changing the ID??? Do not mess with the ID of an existing entity -identifiers must be immutable.

Comment: i remove ID because i want to insert data newly. @Alan Hay

Comment: This is my Entity Code: https://cmmehdi.blogspot.com/2018/09/entity-code-entity-tablename-group.html    @SimonMartinelli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just set the ID null.

The entity is in a managed state and will not be new just because you set the ID to null.

The proper way would be to clone the entity state in a new instance.

You could also try to detach the entity (EntityManager.detach) and then set the ID to null. Maybe it will insert a new row. But as I said this is not the way you should do that.

Read more about entity states here: https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/